# Failing multiplication

Tags: java, random, multiplication

My programm dispalys multiplications of more than 2 components on the console (e.g. 2*3*5=30). The componetns are random numbers. The random numbers are saved in an array and the product of them is calculated b a for loop. The code of this method is

```
public static RandomNumbers productpro(RandomNumbers a[]){
    int r=1;
    for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++){
        r=r*a[j].get();
    }
    return new RandomNumbers(r);
}
```

The constuctor of RandomNumbers is

```
int a=(int) Math.random();
public RandomNumbers(int a){
    this.a=a;
}
```

This code often not works. This is obviously very annoying and confusing.
Thanks for help

Comment: What is the `get()` method doing ? Is it failing for "big" values (it may be an integer overflow) ?

Comment: `This code often not works.` This is not a sufficient explanation. Please specify what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: int a=(int) Math.random(); a will always be 0

Comment: "This code often not works" My guess: if you are multiplying sufficiently many sufficiently large numbers together, you get an integer overflow.

Comment: Protip: write a unit test which passes in fixed values for various test cases, and dependency inject the random number generator in integration tests/production only. The unit test will give you a reliable way of checking that your code does what you want it to do.

Answer (score -1):

The following code prints the expected result.

```
private static class RandomNumbers {

    final int a;

    private RandomNumbers(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    private int get() {
        return a;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toString(a);
    }
}

public static RandomNumbers productpro(RandomNumbers a[]) {
    int r = 1;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        r = r * a[j].get();
    }
    return new RandomNumbers(r);
}

public void test() {
    RandomNumbers[] a = {new RandomNumbers(2), new RandomNumbers(3), new RandomNumbers(5)};
    RandomNumbers r = productpro(a);
    System.out.println("productpro(" + Arrays.toString(a) + ") = " + r);
}
```

If, however, you are experiencing integer overflow you could switch to `BigInteger`.

```
private static class RandomNumbers {

    final BigInteger a;

    private RandomNumbers(BigInteger a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    private RandomNumbers(long a) {
        this.a = BigInteger.valueOf(a);
    }

    private BigInteger get() {
        return a;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return a.toString();
    }
}

public static RandomNumbers productpro(RandomNumbers a[]) {
    BigInteger r = BigInteger.ONE;
    for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
        r = r.multiply(a[j].get());
    }
    return new RandomNumbers(r);
}

public void test() {
    RandomNumbers[] a = {new RandomNumbers(2), new RandomNumbers(3), new RandomNumbers(5)};
    RandomNumbers r = productpro(a);
    System.out.println("productpro(" + Arrays.toString(a) + ") = " + r);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;
public class Mainclass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//creating random numbers
        int [] arr = new int[3];
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++)
            arr[i]= rand.nextInt(100-1)+1;// only generates numbers between 1-100but you can change it
        for(int i =0; i<arr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i]+" ");
       Randomnumbers r = new Randomnumbers(arr);
System.out.println("The product of random numbers");
       System.out.println(r.productpro(arr));
    }

}
//java class of random numbers.
import java.util.*;
public class Randomnumbers {
    int [] arr;
    public Randomnumbers(int [] arr){
        this.arr=arr;

    }
//method to generate product of three random numbers in array
    public int productpro(int [] arr){
        int pro=1;
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
            pro = arr[i]*pro;
        }
        return pro;
    }
}
```